# How to show that the integral part of a binomial expansion is even?

Tags: binomial-theorem

> **Question:**
>
> Show that the integral part of $(7+5\sqrt2)^{2n+1}$ is an even integer.

I can solve questions with power 'n', but have problem with powers such as'2n+1'. Is there any special condition?

Comment: Consider $(7+5\sqrt2)^m+(7-5\sqrt2)^m$. Also please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2490340/finding-greatest-integer-using-expansion?noredirect=1&lq=1 
 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202564/product-of-integral-and-fractional-part-of-binomial-expansion

Comment: I tried but its coming an odd integer.

Comment: Note that since $49=7^2\lt (5\sqrt 2)^2=50$ you have $7-5\sqrt 2\lt 0$ and you will be raising it to an odd power.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=(7+5\sqrt2)^n+(7-5\sqrt2)^n$. Then
$$
a_0=2,
\quad
a_1=14
\quad
a_{n}=14a_{n-1}+a_{n-2} \mbox{ for } n \ge 2
$$
In particular, $a_n$ is always an even integer.

Because $-1 < 7-5\sqrt2 < 0$, the integer part of $(7+5\sqrt2)^n$ is $a_n-1$ when $n$ is even and $a_n$ when $n$ is odd. Hence the claim.