# Finding greatest integer less than or equal to $(\sqrt{b}+a)^n$ if $|{\sqrt{b}-a}|>1$

Tags: binomial-theorem

Today my teacher taught about a method to find the greatest integer less than or equal to $(a+\sqrt{b})^n$, in a method mentioned as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2490340/finding-greatest-integer-using-expansion).

But actually the limitation is that $|{a-\sqrt{b}}|$ must be less than $1$.

My question is how to find the same for $|{a-\sqrt{b}}|>1$ (of course, without using a calculator!), say for $(1+\sqrt{5})^6$.

---

I don't really have an idea  of how to go about it.

Comment: It's a lot easier when powers of the conjugate(s) go to $0$, that's why people point to that case.  Here...well it is easy to see that $\left( 1+\sqrt 5 \right)^6=576+256\,\sqrt 5$.  If you know that $2.236<\sqrt 5 <2.2361$ that suffices.  Don't see an easy alternative.