# Value of Number(1- fractional part)

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> If $p = (8+3\sqrt7)^m$ and $f= p - \lfloor p\rfloor$ where $\lfloor p
>  \rfloor $ denotes the greatest integer function, then the value of
>   $p(1-f)$ is equal to:
>
> a)$ 1$
>
> b)$2$
>
> c) $2^{n}$
>
> d) $2^{2n}$

I have written the binomial expansion of $8+3\sqrt7$ but that doesn't lead me anywhere. How do I attempt this problem? Any hints?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202564/product-of-integral-and-fractional-part-of-binomial-expansion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that $p = (8+3\sqrt 7)^m$ and $f = p - \lfloor p\rfloor$. Let $q = (8-3\sqrt{7})^m$. Now $pq = 1$ as $(8+3\sqrt 7)^m(8-3\sqrt7)^m = 1^m=1$. So $0<q < 1$.

Now using binomial theorem $p+q \in \Bbb Z$ as all square root terms get cancelled.

From here, $p+q = \lfloor p\rfloor + f + q$. Now since $f\in [0,1)$ and $q \in (0,1)$, their sum belongs in $(0,2)$. And since $p+q \in \Bbb Z$ so only possible value for $f+q$ is $1$ or $q = 1-f$.

Thus $p(1-f) = pq = 1.$